# Structuring and searching SQL database/table for GPS coordinates

Tags: php, android, sql

I created a database in SQL locally on my phone for an app and then information is uploaded to a database on a server in the same format. In the tables I have GPS coordinates structured as a string with a tab between latitude and longitude. Looking back it makes more sense to have the database structured so that latitude and longitude are in two separate columns as type doubles (seems like it would perform better for searching and sorting).

Would it be much faster for sorting if I turned the string into two Doubles latitude and longitude columns? Is it even possible to search GPS coordinates in this format: "x.xxxx                y.yyyy"? Is there a better way to sort/store GPS coordinates in SQL tables for searching?

Looking back, I wish I had planned this out more carefully. I know planning saves you lots of time down the road. Well, I suppose that applies here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use separate columns for lat/lon.
Floating point representation may or may not be a good idea; when searching for exact coordinates this would not work too well. When looking for a range of values float will be just fine.
Depending on the size of your table and query patterns you may consider creating indexes for performance.

Comment: If you know your table is going to be somewhat large (in terms of atomic I/O units of the db engine), say more than some 100kb or more than a few thousand records *and* you know which kind of queries will be frequently issued against the table (and if *queries* are expected to happen far more often than *updates* or *inserts*), you should use the *create index* statement to increase performance when searching for certain records.

Answer (score 2):

You can use microdegrees to store the values efficiently as integers.

```
int lat = (int)(location.getLatitude() * 1000000);
int lon = (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1000000);
```

There is a bonus if you are going to add a MapView later on, because Android Maps API is using the same number format in [GeoPoint](http://code.google.com/intl/de/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html#GeoPoint%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: So, is it much more efficient to store values as integers?

Comment: This should not make much of a difference performancewise *in the database* compared to floating point but may be a good approach to mitigate the drawbacks of approximate number representations.

Comment: I do not have experience with the performance of floating point on ARM devices. You will probably save ~50% of space with 4-byte INTEGERs vs. 8-byte REALs in SQLite. Also, the Android docs say ["As a rule of thumb, floating-point is about 2x slower than integer on Android devices."](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#avoidfloat) and recommend to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you need to use the two numbers separately in a calculation they should be kept separately.

If you don't care about the accuracy of your numbers then use type `Double` but be warned numbers are stored as an approximation and not as they appear.

If you require exact output as input then try using `Decimal` or `Numeric` as types.

More information here: [MYSQL precision math](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math.html)